# Jupyter Importing Ipynb files Error: no module named 'mynotebook'

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, importerror

I need to import different `ipynb` files, so I tried this:

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

But I get no module named 'mynotebook' found. (I even tried it with other notebooks names, which definitely exist, but still not working)

Do you have any ideas about what I could do?

```
import io, os, sys, types

from IPython import get_ipython
from nbformat import read
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell

def find_notebook(fullname, path=None):
    name = fullname.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    if not path:
        path = ['']
    for d in path:
        nb_path = os.path.join(d, name + ".ipynb")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path
        # let import Notebook_Name find "Notebook Name.ipynb"
        nb_path = nb_path.replace("_", " ")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path

class NotebookLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
        self.path = path

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        """import a notebook as a module"""
        path = find_notebook(fullname, self.path)

        print ("importing Jupyter notebook from %s" % path)

        # load the notebook object
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = read(f, 4)


        # create the module and add it to sys.modules
        # if name in sys.modules:
        #    return sys.modules[name]
        mod = types.ModuleType(fullname)
        mod.__file__ = path
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__dict__['get_ipython'] = get_ipython
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod

        # extra work to ensure that magics that would affect the user_ns
        # actually affect the notebook module's ns
        save_user_ns = self.shell.user_ns
        self.shell.user_ns = mod.__dict__

        try:
              for cell in nb.cells:
                if cell.cell_type == 'code':
                    # transform the input to executable Python
                    code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
                    # run the code in themodule
                    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        finally:
            self.shell.user_ns = save_user_ns
        return mod



class NotebookFinder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.loaders = {}


    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        nb_path = find_notebook(fullname, path)
        if not nb_path:
            return

        key = path
        if path:
            # lists aren't hashable
            key = os.path.sep.join(path)

        if key not in self.loaders:
            self.loaders[key] = NotebookLoader(path)
        return self.loaders[key]

sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())

import mynotebook
```

I just want to import the code of another jupyter file

Comment: is file name correct? I mean `mynotebook`.

Comment: i think mynotebook was just an example of the code (or is there something i have overlookes). But with other files that actually exist in my folders it wont work too

Answer (score 0):

WOW, i also face this problem. I create a new env and after open jupyter, it can't find nbformat in my new installed env, so just:

```
pip install nbformat
```